# Problem Connecting to Wired Network

Tags: installation, networking, connection, wired, ping

I just installed Ubuntu Desktop on a brand new Dell computer that had windows installed on it. I have the ethernet plugged in, but it does not connect to the internet.

I get an IP address. It has DHCP subnet mask and a default gateway. Even though the gateway is pingable, I cannot ping the gateway.

Can anyone explain why I cannot get to the internet and provide a solution ?

Comment: Can you add the output of `nm-tool` to your question?

Comment: state: connected (global)

device: eth0
type: wired
driver: r8168
state: unmanaged
default: no
hw address: --

capabilities: 
carrier detect: yes
speed: 100mb/s

wired properties
carrier: on

***the driver was an r8169 which I removed and added the most recent r8168 driver using ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661489.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the driver it was trying to use was `r8169` and it wasn't working. I had to blacklist that driver and install an older driver following [this Ubuntu forum thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661489). Then I had to change the autorun file from 'sh' to 'bash'. The internet picked right up, I didn't even have to reboot.

Basically what I needed to do was:

1. Downloading the older `r8168` driver from [RealTeks download page](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=5&PFid=5&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#RTL8111B/RTL8168B/RTL8111/RTL8168%3Cbr%3ERTL8111C/RTL8111CP/RTL8111D%28L%29%3Cbr%3ERTL8168C/RTL8111DP/RTL8111E%3Cbr%3ERTL8105E)
2. Blacklisting `r8169` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` file adding

   ```
   blacklist r8169
   ```
3. Compile the downloaded driver by running `autorun.sh` file.

Refer to the [forum page](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1661489) for detail instruction.